# Openlayers load tiles just outside the map extent, as preloading

Tags: openlayers, extent, xyz

Is there any way I can load tiles just outside the current map view.
The end users pan and zoom a lot so they are constantly seeing tiles that load, I could solve this by loading for example 600px or 2 sets of tiles around the visible map.

I am not looking to map of 200% and scale it down, because that would effect all layers.

So I have a `TileLayer<XYZ>`. I am aware with the option `preload`, but that is not really working for me. It preload on a rough scale that is more annoying than helping in this tileset.

The `Map` as a `maxTilesLoading: 256`.

Is it possible to creata a shadow map/view with a larger extent? and put only the XYZ layer in this?

Comment: Shadow map is possible but currently it might cause problems due to bug which has yet to be fixed https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/14140